# Общая строка для двух RegEx

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Существует ли способ определить **факт** существования строки, удовлетворяющий двум regex в реальном времени.
Например для

`^[0-9]+[A-Z]*$` и `^[4-5]+[B-D]*$`
есть общая строка, например, `45BD`
а у регулярок

`^[0-9]+$` и `^[A-Z]+$`
Общей строки нет

PS: саму строку исать не надо, нужен факт её существования.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярные выражения можно объединить в одно. Если есть 2 выражения `qqq` и `www`, то их можно соединить в следующую конструкцию: `^(?=.*(?:qqq))(?=.*(?:www))`, при этом внутри `www` надо пересчитать номера всех захватываемых нумерованных групп. Остаётся проверить, существует ли строка, удовлетворяющая одному регулярному выражению. Я уже пытался такое [спросить](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837687/178988), но полного ответа не получил.

Comment: Спасибо, это первый шаг к решению

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, исправил косяк в объединённой регулярке.