# Как проверить строку на наличие букв, цифр, знаков препинания и управляющих символов?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из множества строк выбрать те, которые в любой последовательности содержат буквы и/или цифры и/или знаки препинания и/или управляющие символы. То есть нужно отобрать всё кроме строк, которые можно интерпретировать, как целые или вещественные числа. Использую такое регулярное выражение:

`"[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+|[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ ||.*[0-9].*"`

но это не решает задачу.
Нужен шаблон, чтобы идентифицировать подобные строки: `.`  `.123`  `0123`  `01.23`  `123.`  `abc.`  `.abc`  `a.bc`  `[`  `!`  `@`  `#`
`$`  `%`  `^`  `&`  `*`  `(`  `)`  `"`  `№`  `;`  `%`  `:`  `?`  `*`  `\`  `/`  `|`  `>`  `<`  `,` то есть всё, что не выглядит так: `123` `1.23` , всё, что нельзя назвать числом целым или вещественным.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, готовым шаблоном.

Comment: Примеры входов/выходов? `но это не решает задачу` - поподробнее об этом.

Comment: проверка любых последовательностей, состоящих из любого количества знаков препинания или любых символов (не букв и не цифр) возвращает false.

Comment: `Примеры входов/выходов?` ?

Comment: `patternTxt.matcher(".").matches(); //false`

Comment: `patternTxt.matcher("$").matches(); //false`

Comment: `patternTxt.matcher("abc.").matches(); //false`

Comment: под примерами я имел ввиду какие конкретно строки вы собираетесь разбирать и какие символы в этих строках вам надо найти (или не найти) - добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. То, что вы привели, мне, если честно, ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: аот такая простейшая регулярка находит и буквы и цифры `[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]+` - чем она вам не нравится не понятно.

Comment: `"yourstring".matches("(?U)\\p{Alnum}+")`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959656/178988